# HttpWebRequest not sending UserAgent

Tags: c#, post, httpwebrequest

I'm new to looking at the whole Web side of .net, and I've run into a slight issue.

I'm trying to do a HttpWebRequest as below:

```
String uri = "https://skyid.sky.com/signup/";
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)";
request.Method = "GET";
request.GetResponse();
```

Where the uri is pointing to a HTTPS site. But once I look at this in Fiddler, it has removed my UserAgent and only shows Host and Connection: Keep-Alive.

```
CONNECT skyid.sky.com:443 HTTP/1.1
Host: skyid.sky.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

Is this normal with HTTPS or am I simply missing something? Maybe I'm even missing something in Fiddler that it's not showing this to me.

Any help will be appreciated, thanks all!

Comment: If I run this (with a value for `uri` of course), I see the user-agent in fiddler with both HTTP and HTTPS. You've presumably cut out something for your example here, since POSTing empty content is unusual. Could you have cut-out something where you over-wrote the headers collection after setting that header?

Comment: @JonHanna, sorry, I am actually doing a GET, I've changed this in the code above and added some more details. So I am guessing its Fiddler, if you can see the UserAgent.

Comment: You are connecting over HTTPS (443), so all you see here is the CONNECT HTTP verb (which is for initiating HTTPS connections). The actual GET requested will be encrypted when it's sent to the server. In order to see it in Fiddler, there is an advanced option that will help you decrypt encrypted connections to view the actual requests.

Comment: Ah yes. @DanielJoseph could have it. A was assuming you had the fiddler option set that man-in-the-middle's the HTTPS so you can see the CONNECT and the GET, but if you don't then you won't see it (the point of HTTPS is to stop people seeing things, after all).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think that you are looking at the correct Fiddler line. What you have shown is a `CONNECT` verb, not `GET`. The `UserAgent` should be properly set using the `request.UserAgent` property. Another way to debug the request is to [configure network tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty48b824.aspx) at your application level which I personally prefer compared to Fiddler:

```
<configuration>
    <system.diagnostics>
        <sources>
            <source name="System.Net" tracemode="protocolonly" maxdatasize="1024">
                <listeners>
                    <add name="System.Net"/>
                </listeners>
            </source>
        </sources>
        <switches>
            <add name="System.Net" value="Verbose"/>
        </switches>
        <sharedListeners>
            <add 
                name="System.Net"
                type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener"
                initializeData="network.log"
            />
        </sharedListeners>
        <trace autoflush="true"/>
    </system.diagnostics>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Is it valid for Web Service ASMX ? I use Client ( proxy WebService ASMX Reference, not WCF Service REference)  for call ASMX Service.