# How do I capture incoming and outgoing XML from WCF service end

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, web-services

In my solution I have three projects. One is a WCF service, another is a Winforms app from where I am calling the web service, and the last is a class library where class has been design extending soap extension class.

My objective is to capture response & request xml when I am calling the WCF service from my Winforms app. I am getting object reference not set error when I am trying to capture xml.

Here is my class library source code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.Services.Protocols;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Xml;

namespace SoapLogger
{
public class TraceExtension : SoapExtension
{
    private Stream oldStream;
    private Stream newStream;

    private static XmlDocument xmlRequest;
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the outgoing XML request sent to PayPal
    /// </summary>
    public static XmlDocument XmlRequest
    {
        get { return xmlRequest; }
    }

    private static XmlDocument xmlResponse;
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the incoming XML response sent from PayPal
    /// </summary>
    public static XmlDocument XmlResponse
    {
        get { return xmlResponse; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Save the Stream representing the SOAP request
    /// or SOAP response into a local memory buffer.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="stream">
    /// <returns></returns>
    public override Stream ChainStream(Stream stream)
    {
        oldStream = stream;
        newStream = new MemoryStream();
        return newStream;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// If the SoapMessageStage is such that the SoapRequest or
    /// SoapResponse is still in the SOAP format to be sent or received,
    /// save it to the xmlRequest or xmlResponse property.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="message">
    public override void ProcessMessage(SoapMessage message)
    {
        switch (message.Stage)
        {
            case SoapMessageStage.BeforeSerialize:
                break;
            case SoapMessageStage.AfterSerialize:
                xmlRequest = GetSoapEnvelope(newStream);
                CopyStream(newStream, oldStream);
                break;
            case SoapMessageStage.BeforeDeserialize:
                CopyStream(oldStream, newStream);
                xmlResponse = GetSoapEnvelope(newStream);
                break;
            case SoapMessageStage.AfterDeserialize:
                break;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the XML representation of the Soap Envelope in the supplied stream.
    /// Resets the position of stream to zero.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="stream">
    /// <returns></returns>
    private XmlDocument GetSoapEnvelope(Stream stream)
    {
        XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
        stream.Position = 0;
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
        xml.LoadXml(reader.ReadToEnd());
        stream.Position = 0;
        return xml;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Copies a stream.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="from">
    /// <param name="to">
    private void CopyStream(Stream from, Stream to)
    {
        TextReader reader = new StreamReader(from);
        TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(to);
        writer.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());
        writer.Flush();
    }
    #region NoOp
    /// <summary>
    /// Included only because it must be implemented.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="methodInfo">
    /// <param name="attribute">
    /// <returns></returns>
    public override object GetInitializer(LogicalMethodInfo methodInfo,
        SoapExtensionAttribute attribute)
    {
        return null;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Included only because it must be implemented.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="WebServiceType">
    /// <returns></returns>
    public override object GetInitializer(Type WebServiceType)
    {
        return null;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Included only because it must be implemented.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="initializer">
    public override void Initialize(object initializer)
    {
    }
    #endregion NoOp
}
```

Here is how I am calling the web service from my Winforms app:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    using (ServiceRef.TestServiceSoapClient oService = new ServiceRef.TestServiceSoapClient())
    {
        textBox1.Text = oService.HelloWorld("Sudip");
        var soapRequest = SoapLogger.TraceExtension.XmlRequest.InnerXml;
        var soapResponse = SoapLogger.TraceExtension.XmlResponse.InnerXml;
    }
}
```

These two lines are causing the object reference error

```
var soapRequest = SoapLogger.TraceExtension.XmlRequest.InnerXml;
var soapResponse = SoapLogger.TraceExtension.XmlResponse.InnerXml;
```

I just could not figure out why I am getting error.

The Winforms app has an `app.config` where I register my class library assembly to capture the xml. Here is my `app.config` details

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<configuration> 
<system.serviceModel> 
<bindings> 
<basicHttpBinding> 
<binding name="TestServiceSoap"/> </basicHttpBinding> 
</bindings> <client> <endpoint address="http://localhost:6804/Service1.asmx" 
binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TestServiceSoap" 
contract="ServiceRef.TestServiceSoap" name="TestServiceSoap"/> 
</client> 
</system.serviceModel> 
<system.web> 
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" /> 
<webServices> <soapExtensionTypes> 
<add type="SoapLogger.TraceExtension,SoapLogger" priority="1" group="0" /> 
</soapExtensionTypes> </webServices> 
</system.web> 
<startup>
<supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/> 
</startup> </configuration>
```

When I search google just to know how to capture request/response xml then I got this kind of many article. I followed many but nothing works.

This url I followed to get the job done http://jramirezdev.net/blog/c-tip-capturar-los-mensajes-soap-de-un-servicio-asmx-que-hemos-referenciado

What kind of mistake am I making not clear. I set the break point at every method in my class library method but when web service call no method got executed in the class library. I don't want to use any tool like wireshark, fiddler to capture the request/response xml rather want to do same thing programatically.

So please guide me what is my mistake? Why am I getting object reference not set error? Please have a look at my code or go to the url link and tell me what is wrong in my approach

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11956204/httpwebrequest-not-sending-useragent

Comment: not found http://jramirezdev.net/blog/c-tip-capturar-los-mensajes-soap-de-un-servicio-asmx-que-hemos-referenciado

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error was caused because **xmlRequest/xmlResponse** have not been initialized when you access them. Hence, try to check null, or create default instances for them.

From your code they are only initialized in the `ProcessMessage(SoapMessage message){}`, make sure that the method is called before you call

```
 var soapRequest = SoapLogger.TraceExtension.XmlRequest.InnerXml;
 var soapResponse = SoapLogger.TraceExtension.XmlResponse.InnerXml;
```

Hope this helps.

EDIT:

After closely examining your code, I realized that the extension you wrote (**SoapExtension**) was for **ASP.NET XML web services**, and it had no business with a WCF service.

To inspect the request and reply in a WCF service, you can extend your dispatcher on the service side by implementing  **System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.IDispatchMessageInspector**.

You can find the example here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733104%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: can u plzz redirect me to right article on this topic in detail from where i can get full working code sample which i can run in my pc. thanks

Comment: any full real world code using `System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.IDispatchMessageInspector` ?

Comment: are there any alternatives to using IDispatchMessageInspector?

Answer (score 12):

Simply we can trace the request message as.

```
OperationContext context = OperationContext.Current;

if (context != null && context.RequestContext != null)

{

Message msg = context.RequestContext.RequestMessage;

string reqXML = msg.ToString();

}
```

Comment: Valid for client  using WebService ASMX ?

Answer (score 5):

1. Configure [WCF Tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx)
2. Send/receive some messages
3. Get the [SvcTraceViewer.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732023%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) log viewer and open the trace output.
4. Profit.

Answer (score 0):

There is an another way to see XML SOAP - [**custom MessageEncoder**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.channels.messageencoder). The main difference from IDispatchMessageInspector / IClientMessageInspector is that it works on lower level, so it captures original byte content including any malformed xml.

In order to implement tracing using this approach you need to wrap a standard [textMessageEncoding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/wcf/textmessageencoding) with [custom message encoder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/custom-message-encoder-custom-text-encoder) as new [binding element](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.textmessageencodingbindingelement%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and apply that custom binding to endpoint in your [config](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/custom-binding-transport-and-encoding).

Also you can see as example how I did it in my project -
[wrapping](https://github.com/capslocky/WcfSoapLogger/blob/master/src/Library/WcfSoapLogger/EncodingExtension/LoggingBindingElement.cs) textMessageEncoding, logging [encoder](https://github.com/capslocky/WcfSoapLogger/blob/master/src/Library/WcfSoapLogger/EncodingExtension/LoggingEncoder.cs), custom binding [element](https://github.com/capslocky/WcfSoapLogger/blob/master/src/Library/WcfSoapLogger/EncodingExtension/LoggingExtensionElement.cs) and [config](https://github.com/capslocky/WcfSoapLogger/blob/master/src/UsageExamples/ExampleBeta/Client/App.config).